# Is there a way to search only the "read" emails in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, search

Sometimes some mails that I need to search are mostly among those that I have read.

Is there a way to perform this search in Gmail?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add `is:read` to your search terms.

Comment: Thanks! I only knew about the `in:` operator.

Comment: This won't work if a thread has mix of read and unread messages. Is there a way to search only threads where all message were read?

Comment: I mean, it worked .. eleven years ago 